# Why is model.fit() only utilizing a part of my GPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I am training a model with 1.4 million parameters on quite a large dataset with my RTX 3070 and TensorFlow 2.8.0. When I start to train my model, the GPU only gets utilized by like 10-30 %.
Since I would like to utilize the whole GPU performance to speed up training, I have been searching for bottlenecks. Sadly I could not find any.

What I've tried so far:

- Verify that TensorFlow uses my GPU
- Using `tf.data.dataset`
- Increasing the batch size (GPU runs OOM if I go higher than 128)

Am I missing something?

#### Verifying that TF recognizes my GPU

```
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(gpus))
for gpu in gpus:
  tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
```

> Num GPUs Available:  1

#### Training

```
batch_size = 128
dataset = tf.data.experimental.load("./data/dataset.tfrecords")
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)

# print dataset size after batching
print(f"Dataset size: {tf.data.experimental.cardinality(dataset).numpy()}")

# Use roughly 10% for validation
test_dataset = dataset.take(1000) 
train_dataset = dataset.skip(1000)

history = model.fit(
    train_dataset, 
    batch_size=batch_size, # dataset batch size will be prioritized
    epochs=30, 
    callbacks=[save_best_checkpoint, tensorboard],
    validation_data=test_dataset,
    use_multiprocessing=True, workers=8
)
```

> Dataset size: 9531

> Epoch 1/30
> 1/8547 [..............................] - ETA: 36:30:07 - loss: 2.1827 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1678

#### Task Manager window

[image: Task Manager Window]

Comment: It is silly to say there are no bottleneck, you cannot fully use the GPU because there are bottlenecks, that you cannot use a larger batch size in order to increase utilization, is a bottleneck.

Comment: Where do you store your training/validation dataset?

Comment: @SlawomirOrlowski my dataset is stored on a SSD. I load it as a TensorFlow dataset and split it into train and test afterwards.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I guess you are right. I was just hoping that there might be something else I'm missing.

Comment: For me it is strange that you have ~24% of 3D engine occupation during CUDA computing. Maybe this affects CUDA performance?